# Migration fail because Realm accessed before migration

Tags: ios, realm

I am using storyboards and some of the viewcontrollers fetch from the Realm as default property values? Because of that the application access the Realm before `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is called. So basically exception raised every time app launches and tries to do the Realm migration.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Further, since we are in dev stage and we don't want to deal with migration every time we made changes to the Realm object models, is there a way to just purge the Realm file and have a fresh start if migration is detected to be needed? I find an issue reported on github (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1692) but it seems no solution is provided. PS, I am using the latest Realm for iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're unable to control which order the storyboards are being loaded automatically by iOS in contrast to the app delegate methods, my recommendation would be to remove the initial storyboard setting from your app's info.plist file and simply manually set up and display it from your app's delegate instead:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

    self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

This will let you explicitly control *when* the storyboard is loaded, letting you do it after your initial Realm setup.

If you're constantly tweaking your model objects during development and don't need to handle migrations just yet, one possible (But slightly hacky) way of doing it is to simply call `Realm()` for the first time, and if it throws an exception (Which it will if it needs to perform a migration), catch the exception and use it to simply delete the Realm file from disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works. As for the hacky way to delete the realm file, I am not sure if there is a less hacky way preferably an official API from Realm that can achieve the same result.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help! Yeah, I'm curious too as to if there was a reason why the option to automatically delete older schema Realm files wasn't included in the Realm Configuration feature. I'll investigate that one!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Worked great. The only step missing is to make sure you delete "Main" from the target's "General > Deployment Info > Main Interface" setting.